# IntelliJ IDEA - Use packages installed in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, bash, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA for development, but for most of the time I use Ubuntu when at work. However, when at home, I have a personal machine running Windows (and no, for some personal reason I cannot remove Windows or dual-boot it with Ubuntu). Windows has WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), luckily, but is it possible in IntelliJ IDEA to use packages I installed in Ubuntu on Windows's apt-get? This is so that I will install all my packages in the Ubuntu on Windows, instead of Windows itself.

Thanks!

Comment: What "packages" are specific to any OS? IntelliJ is mostly a collection of Java files. And you don't `apt-get` those

Comment: what I mean is such things as node/npm, for example. or python, or even the jdk itself. I want to install them in Ubuntu on Windows then set intellij to use that instead of having to install jdk on windows.

Comment: I would be surprised if that was possible. For example, Python `os` module would be very closely tied to the WSL environment, so trying to import that module and run it via Windows wouldn't go over so well. That's why there are differences in the EXE windows packages and DEB packages. Things are compiled differently.

Comment: I just thought it would be possible since Windows has a Linux subsystem already, but I guess it was a stupid question to ask after all. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but a partial answer for someone looking to do similar is to change the path to the *Terminal Shell path* from cmd.exe to wsl.exe

This would mean you open up the Subsystem for Linux for any IntelliJ terminal (that would normally have been the Windows shell).

I'm not sure how far this goes for extra items like Node (as I don't have the Ultimate Edition to check).  But it should be easier to run things using WSL of course.

To find the setting, open IntelliJ settings...

File > Settings... [Ctrl+Alt+S]

Search for 'Shell path'
Under Tools and Terminal, you should see the relevant setting highlighted.

[Rough location of Shell path setting in IntelliJ IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2YiL.png)